# Part identification of an element used in the snout of a micro-scale whale

Tags: part-identification

I need help identifying this part:

[image]

I would think something bionicle, but going through the list on bricklink I couldn't find anything, it's sort of similar to a bionicle eye, but not quite.

Answer (score 15):

This is tricky one. According to my research this element is foot/boot of [Belville figures](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=M&catString=48) and Bricklink doesn't have dedicated entry for this piece. Perhaps it isn't meant to be disassembled/assembled, but that doesn't stop AFOLs from doing so.

[image]

In case somebody would be looking to ID the bottom part of the same sub-assembly it looks to be [Belville, Clothes Child's Leg Cast](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=legcast#T=C&C=1)

[image]

Comment: Amazing work, @Alex!

Comment: "Perhaps it isn't meant to be disassembled/assembled, but that doesn't stop AFOLs from doing so." The same image is using a disassembled minifigure hand for the one of the masts of the ship, so it's pretty clear whoever made the model doesn't care about that! ;)

Comment: @nick012000 maybe that person had his Belville figure badly damaged and salvaged some bits :)

Comment: @nick012000 The hands **are** meant to be detached, and they **do** have separate inventory entries on BrickLink.

Comment: @RSchulz I'm not quite sure about such statement. Hands always come attached. And when you buy LEGO set it comes with loose elements which you need to put together (assemble), so at no point you need to remove hands apart. Speaking of arms - these also have BL entry. And this is definitely done to meet AFOL's needs as their removal isn't straightforward, especially if you don't want to damage torso/arms. So the fact that some elements have entry in BL catalog doesn't mean they were supposed to be removable.

Comment: I was trying to think of a set where the hands were clearly meant to be interchanged, but nothing came to mind. I agree with all your points. I just have this weird impression that there was a minifig where you were supposed to swap the boxing gloves for hands, or swap out a hook for a hand, or some such. Perhaps it is just all the times I had to do that to restore minifigs to factory configuration after kids messed with them.